# Creating and returning a model with a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a couple of endpoints for getting/posting comments on notes in this application.

The `GET` endpoint uses Eloquent's `with` method to include the comments' author data with the response:

```
public function getComments(Note $note) {
    return $note->comments()->with(['author'])->get();
}
```

How can I also include the author data when creating/returning an Eloquent model? Here is my current method:

```
public function postComment(Note $note, Request $request) {
    $user = $this->appUserRepo->getFromRequest($request);
    $text = $request->text;
    $comment = $note->comments()->create([
        'app_user_id' => $user->id,
        'text' => $text
    ]);
    return $comment;
}
```

I'm looking for something like this (but this doesn't work):

```
public function postComment(Note $note, Request $request) {
    $user = $this->appUserRepo->getFromRequest($request);
    $text = $request->text;
    $comment = $note->comments()->create([
        'app_user_id' => $user->id,
        'text' => $text
    ]);
    return $comment->with(['author']);
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should try using:

```
$comment->load('author');
return $comment;
```

to load `author` relationship for comment.

Comment: Is it possible to use "`refresh`" to get all relationships like this?, because it's not working but I've seen code that works correctly with this:

`$comment = auth()->user()->comments()->create([
            'body'  =>  $request->body,
            'video_id'  =>  $video->id,
            'comment_id'    =>  $request->comment_id
        ])->refresh();`

With the above code I don't get any relationship.